# NSURLCache not caching url

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, nsurlconnection

I create the url like so, which is part of a function that is called in a background thread.

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
  NSData *pageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

And when I try to cache it

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024
                                                         diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024
                                                             diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
}
```

However, if I open the app, close it, and try opening it again, the app takes the same amount of time to load and there is no noticeable improvement in speed.  I'm wondering if there is an iOS limitation with caching, or if I have implemented the code incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the proper e-tag in your request? Is your server returning a 200, or a 304?

In order to know that the cached data can be used, the server needs to indicate that it hasn't changed.

Comment: Is this something I have to NSLog to the console to check?

Comment: If you own the server you are hitting, it would be easiest to check your server logs.

If it is not and you really need caching behavior, I would suggest using the AFNetworking library for your network requests, so that you can see the HTTP request parameters (including eTag and response status codes)

Comment: Would it be less trouble to just manually store the url's with NSFileManager or NSUserDefaults?

Comment: I would not store them in the user defaults. NSData has a writeToFile: method that you could use to cache it on disk yourself. To get a generalized solution for HTTP caching though, I think you would be better off to move your HTTP request to AFNetworking.